# Make comment time limit enforcement match comment vote time limit enforcement

Tags: feature-request, comments, time-limit

The time limit for comment voting is 5 seconds.  If you try to vote before 5 seconds you get a popup and have to finish waiting the 5 seconds.

However, for posting a comment the limit is 15 seconds.  If you post a comment within that 15 seconds you get a popup **and the time limit is reset**.  So now you have to wait another 15 seconds to post.

This isn't a huge deal, but the inconstancy makes the UI slightly more frustrating. My request is to make the comment timer not reset just like the comment vote timer does not reset.

Comment: I wish it didn't apply to mods...